# How can I reconfigure Apache from source code using installing openssl?

Tags: linux, openssl, centos

In a server linux Centos 5 64bit, I have compile from the source code the webserver Apache version 2.4.6.

Below, the configure instruction that I have used.

```
./configure --enable-mods-shared=reallyall --with-suexec-caller=apache --enable-cache --enable-cache-disk --with-ldap --enable-ldap --enable-authnz-ldap
```

Now, I must recompile the webserver Apache to using the new installed version of openssl (1.0.1e-fips).

What is the correct syntax to reconfigure Apache to using the current version of openssl installed on the server?

Many thanks at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you unfortunately didn't mention how you installed OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips (and where), this can't be answered. Based on 1.0.1e-fips, I see some chances that you used my [openssl101e](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=21528) RPM package from EPEL 5 (even more important: `openssl101e-devel`). If so, run

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/include/openssl101e"
export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I/usr/include/openssl101e"
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/usr/include/openssl101e"
```

before `./configure`. Otherwise you first need to reveal more details about your OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips installation/update.